# Why php - if ($mail->send()) is not working properly

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have tried to use this php code for a web site contact us page. Error messages for field validation are working fine. However its not working the $result messages properly as its sending the wrong message.

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["submit"]) && $_POST["submit"] == 'Send')
    {

        $name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '';
        $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
        $subject = isset($_POST['subject']) ? $_POST['subject'] : '';
        $message = isset($_POST['message']) ? $_POST['message'] : '';
        $human = isset($_POST['human']) ? intval($_POST['human']) : '';
        $error = array();

        // Check if name has been entered
        if (empty($name)) {
            $error['name'] = 'Please enter your name';
        }

        // Check if email has been entered and is valid
        if (empty($email) || !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $error['email'] = 'Please enter a valid email address';
        }

        //Check if message has been entered
        if (empty($message)) {
            $error['message'] = 'Please enter your message';
        }

        //Check if simple anti-bot test is correct
        if ($human !== 5) {
            $error['human'] = 'Your anti-spam is incorrect';
        }

        // If there are no errors, send the email
        if (empty($error)) {
            $mail = new PHPMailer;

            $mail->isSMTP();
            $mail->SMTPDebug = 3;
            $mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
            $mail->addAddress('example@example.net', 'User');


            $mail->Subject = $_POST['subject'];
            $mail->Body    = $_POST['message'];

            // From here the code is not working properly
            if ($mail->send()) {
                $result = '<div class="alert alert-success">Sorry there is a problem by sending your message. Please try again later.</div>';
            } else {
                //echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;exit;
                $result = '<div class="alert alert-success">Thank you for your message and we will get back to you as soon as possible.</div>';
            }  
        }
    }
?>
```

Can you identify the error of this code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/

Comment: `send()` and `Send()` are two different animals in PHPMailer

Comment: your $result success message says sorry, and $result sorry message thank you. dicy

Comment: @Fred-ii- no they are not - PHP is not case sensitive for functions and methods.

Comment: You could try reading the readme and examples that are provided with PHPMailer. They *all* show how to get the ErrorInfo after sending fails.

Comment: @Synchro I have seen a few questions (posted this year actually) where someone posted PHPMailer code and the functions used didn't use the camel case syntax. Bizarre? You're telling me. I didn't dream this, pretty sure. I hope not *lol*

Comment: It is confusing! Old versions of PHPMailer were pretty haphazard - A couple of years ago I changed things to conform as closely as possible to the PSR-2 coding standard without breaking BC - one of the main changes is that it uses camel case with leading lower case, so `addAddress` replaced `AddAddress` etc, but they are functionally identical. You can't change case of property names without breaking, so they stayed the same. Unfortunately, there are lots of ancient and obsolete tutorials around using the old names (PHPMailer has been around since 2001!) and they often come back to haunt us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have added incorrect message. 
 on `if ($mail->send()) {` you have returned error message.

change the check to  `!$mail->send()` that's it.

```
if (!$mail->send()) {
```

If that doesn't work, try this to debug:

```
    if(!$mail->send()) {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } 
    else {
        echo "Message has been sent successfully";
    }
```

Comment: add ! before $mail->send()

Comment: $mail->send() probably responds with boolean, true when the mail is sent and false when not (you should check the method before using it). If the mail is sent you are displaying the wrong message. To have a better visualization of the message for failed send please use "alert alert-danger" css class;

Comment: Yeah Thanks I have corrected all those and I understood the mistake of that part. However its not working properly as even its sending message its giving the wrong result message. Do you have any suggestions where I have to look at more.

Answer (score 0):

Try to print the `error` using `ErrorInfo` function

```
if(!$mail->Send()) {// Send not send
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo "Message sent!";

}
```